# unable to inject values into my html file

Tags: html, swift, wkwebview

im trying to loading an html file with a javascript into my application, but i need to pass user credentials to that html file:

```
HTML file:
#  CHAT HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@hiveio/dhive@latest/dist/dhive.js"></script>

    <!--<script src="https://chat.peakd.com/stwidget.js"></script>-->
    
 <script src="script.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <script>
        var user = '';
        var postingKey = '';
      /*var client = new dhive.Client(["https://api.hive.blog", "https://api.hivekings.com", "https://anyx.io", "https://api.openhive.network"]);
      client.database
        .getDiscussions("trending", { tag: "writing", limit: 1 })
        .then(function(discussions) {
          document.body.innerHTML += "<h1>" + discussions[0].title + "</h1>";
          document.body.innerHTML += "<h2>by " + discussions[0].author + "</h2>";
          document.body.innerHTML +=
            '<pre style="white-space: pre-wrap">' + discussions[0].body + "</pre>";
        });*/

        function getUserFromWebView(){
              return user;
          }

           function getPstKeyFromWebView() {
              return postingKey;
          }


        // Function to give focus to the element with the specified ID
    function giveFocusToElement(elementId) {
        var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        if (element) {
            console.log('give focus');
            element.focus();
        }
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chatDiv"></div>
    <script>
   

     var stwidget = new StWidget('https://chat.peakd.com/t/hive-193552/0');
        stwidget.properties = { "requireLogin": false,
                                "showSidebar": true,
                                "sidebar": 2,
                                "sidebar2enableSharedView": false,
                                "sidebarToggleByChannelNameOnDirectGroup": true,
                                "streambarExpand": true,
                                "streambarMode": 1,
                                "sidebarAddButton": 1,
                                "communityChannelNameFormat": "<title>/<name>",
                                "messageIconFlexClass": "block text-justify lg:text-left sm:flex",
                                "messageIconClass": "iconFloat",
                                "--appCommunityIconFontSize": "18px",
                                "--appCommunityIconSize": "42px",
                                "homeTabCommunities": true,
                                "homeTabPreferences": true,
                                "homeTabThemes": false,
                                "onlyPrependCommunities": false,
                                "prependCommunities": [
                                    "hive-193552"
                                ],
                                "defaultTheme": {"bg0":"#ff112d","bg1":"#ff112d","bg2":"#ffffff","bg3":"#ffffff","bgbtn1":"#2e8336","bgbtn2":"#d9d9d7","bgowner":"#007b00","bgadmin":"#2368d5","bgmod":"#2e8336","bgconote":"#ff112d","bgunote":"#ff112d"},
                                "--appFontFamily": "'Arial'",
                                "--appFontSize": "16px",
                                "--appMessageFontFamily": "''New Heterodox Mono',monospace'",
                                "--appMessageFontSize": "16px"
                                };
        const curUser = getUserFromWebView();
        if (curUser != null && curUser != ''){
            stwidget.setUser(curUser);
            stwidget.setPostingKey(getPstKeyFromWebView(), dhive);
           
        }else{
            
            stwidget.setUser(user);
        }
        let defaultWidth = 450;
        if (screen.width < 750){
            defaultWidth = screen.width - 90;
        }
        let defaultHeight = 500;
        if (screen.height < 520){
            defaultHeight = screen.height - 60;
        }
        var element = stwidget.createElement(defaultWidth+'px', defaultHeight+'px', false/*overlay*/, false /*resizable*/);

        document.getElementById("chatDiv").appendChild(element);

        //set focus
        window.onload = function() {
            giveFocusToElement('.scrollBoxContent');
        };
        //setInterval(giveFocusToElement('#app'), 3000);

    </script>

    <style>
        #app{
            overflow: scroll;
        }
        .h-screen.flex.flex-col.appbg0.appfg0.border-r-1.sidebar{
            background-color: #ff112d !important;
        }
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

The first way i tried to set the user and postingKey values is as follow:

```
 webView.configuration.defaultWebpagePreferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true
          
                
        self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: htmlFileURL.absoluteString)!))
      let userScript = WKUserScript(source: "user = 'user';", injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
                let postingKeyScript = WKUserScript(source: "postingKey = 'abcdefg';", injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
                webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)
                webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(postingKeyScript)
```

but it didnt work,
the second way i did as following:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        let setUserScript = "user = 'user';"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(setUserScript) { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error calling setUser: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("setUser function called successfully")
            }
        }


        let setPstingKeyScript = "postingKey = 'abcde';"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(setPstingKeyScript) { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error calling setPstingKey: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("setPstingKey function called successfully")
            }
        }
       }
```

no error was returned, but still it didnt work, i dont have the username and the password in my html file